# Deploying from Django/Python3 to Google Compute Engine Managed VM

Tags: django, apache, google-app-engine, python-3.x, google-compute-engine

*I am new to cloud development and after reading around the net, I don't think this question has been answered.*

I have a program that uses `Django (written in python3)` and `bootstrap`.
  *I've been working on this program for a while, and I think I've prepared it enough to be deployed.*

I am using `Google Cloud`/`Google Compute Engine` to deploy this application.  I am very well aware that **Django's webserver is not designed for deployment**, and that the best solution is said to use `mod_wsgi`.  Because of this, I have set up a `local VM` which uses `Apache` and `mod_wsgi` to serve the application.

I have decided that it is time to deploy the application, *but I am not sure if the direction I want to take is even possible*. 
 From my understanding, Google Cloud's managed VM's, to me, seem to have a much larger benefit than unlocked VMs.  However, I am well aware of the limitations of GCE and how the managed VMs should either use familiar runtimes or custom docker images.

What I am not sure of, however, is **the exact steps needed to deploy my mod_wsgi** application built by `Django` to `GCE`.

- *Does the apache environment in the managed `VMs` support `mod_wsgi`?*
- *Would I have to use multiple `runtimes/docker` images to achieve this?*
- *Would it be better to just use one of the `click-to-deploy` images or a custom image to deploy this application, and not used managed `VMs`?*

**To clarify, the apache, Django, and python I used are all the most recent versions.**

Answer (score 1):

This is still a question without  many good answers, if any, on stack overflow. Ironically, I got the most benefit from using digital ocean's tutorial, [How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04), which basically walks you through setup from the ground up. I had a local VM running Ubuntu 16.04 so I was able to make two passes, once in practice, then in cloud which definitely helped me get over some hurdles relatively quickly.

I would also review [Django Security Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/) for production as part of your deployment.

Comment: Links die - SO does not. Bring it here.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved using a Managed VM [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes). This basically means you provide your own custom [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) with your app, and using that you can specify any base docker image you want and install any additional dependencies you need (eg. via pip or apt-get). For example, you could use the [google/python base image](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#base_images) and install apache and mod_wsgi in the Dockerfile using apt-get, or just use a base image that [already has apache and mod_wsgi](https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=mod_wsgi&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0) set up for you.

Probably the best thing to do first is to just run through the Python [Hello World tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world), because by the end of it you will see exactly how Docker ties in to Managed VMs and the syntax needed to set up your Dockerfile the way you want it.